# collectionview cell for xib not showing

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a custom cell for my collection view. I have a xib named `AccountCell`:

[image]

In my view containing the collection view:

```
    profileViewController = p;
    collectionView.dataSource = profileViewController
    collectionView.registerClass(SocialAccountCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "accountCell")
```

and then in the data source:

```
func collectionView(_collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    println("getting cell")
    let cell = _collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("accountCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SocialAccountCell
    cell.test()
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
   return user!.accounts.count
}
```

`SocialAccountCell.swift`:

```
class SocialAccountCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
  func test()
  {
      println("Hello From collection cell")
  }
}
```

Both `"getting cell"` and `"Hello From collection cell"` are printed but no blue cell appears in the collection view.

I tried adding an image to the cell to check if it was just the blue not working. Still no indication of any cell appearing.

What steps am I missing here?

Comment: Are you setting the reuse identifier on your custom cell xib?

Comment: @FormigaNinja yes but it doesnt seem to do anything because without `collectionView.registerClass(SocialAccountCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "accountCell")` the app crashes.

Comment: Is just the blue part that is not showing? Can you see any indication of the cell?

Comment: @IcaroNZ as far as i can tell there is no cell.

Comment: Have you try to hardcode the number of cells in `func collectionView(_collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
   return user!.accounts.count
}`

Comment: Try to use registerNib instead registerClass

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're using `xib` to define a cell, I think you'd use `collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "someNib", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "accountCell")`, or else you'd setup UI elements in code.